# Connection through ip address

Tags: java

I am trying to obtain the ip address from a text file so when I use the following code it does noy work..

```
  System.out.println("get = "+get);     //get is where the ip address is stored after reading from file and it is successfully received as well
  Socket client=new Socket(get,5000);
```

I have even tried the same thing through InetAddress as follows..but it does not work as well.

```
  InetAddress ik= InetAddress.getByName(get);
  Socket client=new Socket(ik,5000);
```

but when I manually provide the ip in get it works.I dont understand where am I wrong?

```
  String get="192.168.1.224";
```

Comment: Any exception error message? Did you try printing value of get in both cases ?

Comment: Just for sake, did you try to do get.trim() ?

Comment: Try printing like this: `System.out.println("get = \"" + get + "\"");` This way you will see if there is any spaces at the beginning or end which might interfere.

Comment: You should post the code where you actually read the ip address... And also post the error that you are getting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
System.out.println("get = "+get.trim());
Socket client=new Socket(get,5000);
```